# Django website optimization: Too many calls to core python functions?

Tags: python, django, orm, query-optimization, django-extensions

I am trying to optimize load time of page and found one request which is fetching data and taking ~6-7sec. I used `runprofileserver` of [django-extensions](https://github.com/django-extensions/django-extensions) and found out that it is not database which is causing delay but excessive call to core python methods. Have a look on top 30 time intensive calls

[image]

Here we can see that mostly due to large number of call to in-build python methods this request is taking more than 5sec to execute. I want to know, are following conclusions right?

1. SQL queries or ORM is not major culprit (Though it is data intensive request but it ranks on 6th with 0.194 sec) ?
2. There is not much scope of optimization as major calling are happening to in-build python functions of posixpath.py and genericpath.py ?

Can you please suggest ways, if any, to optimize this after looking above data?

Comment: Seems like it's not django related if the bottleneck is all the other processing that's taking place. Hard to tell what to optimize without looking at what's happening in those methods. Also, check if you're getting same results using cProfiler, and does debug toolbar also imply similar results? If the processing is taking that long, maybe you're trying to do too much in the view? Let me make a guess here... Is it possible for you to make some of those processing asynchronously (using celery), and simply show the results in the view? If not, then it's python optimization question I am afraid.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use the cached template loader https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/templates/api/#django.template.loaders.cached.Loader

Comment: I am not using templates to generate front-end but AngularJS